# Reusable Custom WordPress Meta Boxes

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

Im using [Reusable Custom WordPress Meta Boxes](https://github.com/tammyhart/Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes) in order to add custom meta boxes to my theme.

One of the requirements is that i have WYSIWYG Editor in metabox.

Part of the code to get that thing is:

```
array(
        'label' => __('Availability content'),
        'desc'  => __('Some desc'),
        'id'    => 'availability_text',
        'type'  => 'editor'
    ),
```

Now when I save post, information in metabox is saved **but its not formatted and images that were in editor are lost**.

Why that could happen and how to solve it?

I noticed that it removes formatting, strips out `p <br> h1` tags etc

Comment: Could you please share me the content that you are saving in to it so that i can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Is your content working fine in the default post editor?

Comment: @VinodDalvi yes it is working fine in post editor. The content that I'm trying to save is formatted text (heading, paragraph tags and images). Also I have tried to build my own metabox with WYSIWYG editor and it works fine, which leaves me with conclusion that there is problem with saving with custom metaboxes from https://github.com/tammyhart/Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with meta_box_sanitize function, located at https://github.com/tammyhart/Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes/blob/master/metaboxes/meta_box.php, line 333-355.

I replaced:

```
default:
return sanitize_text_field( $string );
```

with

```
default:
return wp_kses_post( $string );
```

And it works!

Just discovered that it would also work this:

```
array(
        'label' => __('Availability content'),
        'desc'  => __('Some desc'),
        'id'    => 'availability_text',
        'type'  => 'editor',
        'sanitizer' => array( // array of sanitizers with matching kets to next array
            'type' => 'wp_kses_post'
        ),
),
```